# javascript for loop not printing right dataset for each button in a class

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, socket.io

I am creating a voting webapp using flask, javascript and socketio. I am looping through all the buttons belonging to the `vote` class. I am trying to get their data-vote values. For some reason, when printing the dataset.vote for the buttons when clicking them (as specified in a function below), it outputs the dataset.vote for the last button when clicking both buttons. Could someone point out my error and help me fix it? If you need me to specify something, I'd be happy to do so.

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
sock =SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@sock.on("cast_vote")
def f(data):
    vote = data["vote"]
    print(vote)
    emit("vote_result", {"vote":vote}, broadcast=True)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>SocketIO</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='main.js')}}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="main"></ul>
        <button class="vote" data-vote="no">No</button>
    <button class="vote" data-vote="yes">Yes</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
  var sock = io.connect(location.protocol+"//"+document.domain+":"+location.port)
  sock.on("connect", ()=>{
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".vote");
    let i;
    for(i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i){
      button = buttons[i];
      button.onclick = () => {
        console.log(button.dataset.vote);
        let vote = button.dataset.vote;
        console.log(vote);
        sock.emit("cast_vote", {"vote":vote});
      };
    }
  });
  sock.on("vote_result", (data)=>{
    newli = document.createElement("li");
    newli.innerHTML=data["vote"]
    document.querySelector("#main").append(newli);
  });
});
```

Output:

```
yes
yes
yes
yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare some of your variables as `global` one and you should avoid that.

Try changing this code

```
for(i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i){
  button = buttons[i];
```

to this one

```
for(i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i){
  let button = buttons[i];
```

Also take a look at your code and add `var/let/const` to all other variables that you use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when creating button without using a `const` or `let` declaration you create a global variable, if you write button in your browser's console it will print the reference of the element that it reuses in each iteration, that is why the call to `dataset.vote` returns `yes` in your case the solution is to use the declaration `let` or `const` for example

```
let button = buttons[i];
```

You can simplify your code taking advantage of the chaining in javascript, please take a look at this example

```
document.querySelectorAll("button.vote").forEach((button) =>
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const vote = event.target.dataset.vote;

    console.log(vote);
    sock.emit("cast_vote", { vote });
  })
);
```